# Using Bootstrap framework/foundation framework with Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, html5, boot-strap

Is it possible to use bootstrap/foundation with SharePoint to improve the front end look of SharePoint 2010 or 2013?

Can anyone suggest anything related to this?

Thanks

Comment: Depends what you aiming to do, I mean in which context? Page Layout, App, Web Part, everywhere?

Answer (score 4):

It does not work well OOTB, but there are serveral modified versions available.

[Here is Twitter Bootstrap for 2010 (and some 2013)](http://bootstrapsharepoint.codeplex.com/)

[Here is Bootstrap 2 for SharePoint 2010 (beta)](http://responsivesharepoint.codeplex.com/releases/view/100318)

[Here is Bootstrap 2 for SharePoint 2010 (beta)](http://responsivesharepoint.codeplex.com/releases/view/99472)

[Here is Bootstrap 3 for SharePoint 2013 (beta)](https://responsivesharepoint.codeplex.com/releases/view/112845)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Robert - SharePoint has one of the worst markup around. While the Master page, page layouts are easier to work with - when it comes to Bootstrap, the inner lists are even worse.

I built a Javascript Plugin that you can add into your CEWP. http://michaelsoriano.com/sharepoint-bootstrap-using-spservices-and-jquery/

This requires SPServices, jQuery and Bootstrap.