# Twitter-Bootstrap 3 for SharePoint 2013 installation

Tags: installation, boot-strap

I am trying to install Twitter-Bootstrap 3 on a 2013 SharePoint site. I can't seem to install it properly (Col-- class isn't recognized therefore pages aren't responsive) and I can't find any documentation that may help me. Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: How are you trying to achieve it? Are you referencing the bootstrap script files in master page? Do you have jQuery referenced as well?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the SharePoint specific one? You can find the one's specifically modified for SharePoint in this question: [Using Bootstrap framework/foundation framework with Sharepoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93976/using-bootstrap-framework-foundation-framework-with-sharepoint)